# connecting to neo4j 2.2.5 using Tinkerpop3

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have neo4j 2.2.5 community edition and java code on the same machine (windows 7), I an trying the following code to connect to neo4j (without HA)

```
Configuration config = new BaseConfiguration();
config.setProperty(Neo4jGraph.CONFIG_DIRECTORY, "C:\\Users\\mike\\Documents\\Neo4j");
 config.setProperty("gremlin.neo4j.conf.cache_type", "none");
 Graph toyGraph = Neo4jGraph.open(config);
```

but I am getting the following exception

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Users\mike\Documents\Neo4j
                at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:334)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:108)
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:95)
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
                at org.neo4j.tinkerpop.api.impl.Neo4jFactoryImpl.newGraphDatabase(Neo4jFactoryImpl.java:44)
                at org.neo4j.tinkerpop.api.Neo4jFactory$Builder.open(Neo4jFactory.java:32)
                at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:130)
                at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.open(Neo4jGraph.java:144)
                at ca.concordia.orchestrator.test.TestNeo4j.main(TestNeo4j.java:33)
            Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@7c0edd8f' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:489)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:106)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:330)
                ... 9 more
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/document/Fieldable
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.NodeRangeDocumentLabelScanStorageStrategy.<init>(NodeRangeDocumentLabelScanStorageStrategy.java:71)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newKernelExtension(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:73)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newKernelExtension(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:39)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:66)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483)
                ... 12 more
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                ... 17 more
```

I have following dependencies in pom.xml

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
                <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1-incubating</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
                <artifactId>tinkergraph-gremlin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1-incubating</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Neo4j -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-gremlin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1-incubating</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl is NOT Apache 2 licensed - more information
                below -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl</artifactId>
                <version>0.1-2.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

Any idea what could be the problem ? Does Thinkerpop3 work with neo4j 2.2.5?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that there are problems with dependency versions in your setup.

If you look at [neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl) - you can see that there is currently release for Neo4j 2.2.5 in master. But maven central has 2.2 version.

Ensure that you are using correct version of Neo4j dependencies everywhere.

In maven [dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) can be helpful.